# Is it possible to see when a share folder was shared in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares

Basically I have discovered that my C:\Users and all sub-folders have been made into a share and shared to "Everyone", so I am very interested to know when this was done. I have since enabled auditing of share-folder access, but that's not going to help me find out who did it (presumably it happened while my computer was unattended), which if I know when it happened then I can have a guess.

How can I find out when it was shared? (if that is even possible)

Comment: People are unhappy with my answer so I deleted it. Best of luck

Comment: Geez, tuck tail and run because of one down vote?

Comment: Welp... anyone know if it's possible? (and if it is, then how?)